# What is the correct way to take Creatine?

Tags: creatine

I have read that Creatine must be taken with juice, such as Grape juice, because the sugars help it get absorbed by the body. Is this true?

Also, what time is it best to take Creatine? Before or After working out? First thing in the morning?

Also, what cycling interval should be used? Is 8 weeks on, 4 weeks off, ok? Or is 4 weeks on and 4 weeks off better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creatine is like any other supplement; taking a megadose at once will give you progressively worse absorption, so mixing it with other things is useful to help you get more.  It doesn't have to be juice.  It can be milk or any other liquid you enjoy.  I've known some people who put it in their tea.  I personally think the texture of that is pretty vile, but whatever, works for them.

As for when to take it, before and after is the generally accepted wisdom, because those are the times your body will be making good use of the nutrition you're providing it.  Taking it when you don't need it just makes it more likely that it will get passed with your urine.

Someone else will have to handle the cycling question; I have only my own experience to draw upon there and I consider that way too little to make a statement on.

Comment: Can you find a source for your first two paragraphs? I'd be interested to read more.

Comment: @Sparafusile, perhaps you can ask a more basic question about creatine, so YYY can elaborate even further there ;-)

Comment: Fortunately or unfortunately, most of my answers come from discussing questions in depth with personal trainers, shadowing chiropractors and osteopaths, and otherwise associating closely with fitness and health professionals to help my diabetic condition.  The best I could do for you on the concepts of dosage would be to cite some textbooks I've obtained from some of my mentors (not very useful to you).  If you had a more specific question I might be able to google something up, though.

Comment: The sugar can help absorption - it's not just the liquid that matters - but when I'm on creatine, I personally choose not to use a sugary beverage just because I'm not willing to take the negatives of the sugar in order to get the extra creatine absorption.

Answer (score 1):

5 grams with your post-workout shake is the best way to take it.

You can have it for 8 weeks then givve a 4 weeks of, but some people don't even cycle it.

There's no known any side effects for creatine if you consume it responsibly.

Some people talk about kidney failure etc but it's more about consuming right amount of water every day.